# Are "bugs"-tagged questions processed when the question is closed?

Tags: discussion, bug-reporting-process

I have asked a question that has, in my opinion, been marked as duplicate much too hastily.

I have understood that posts tagged "bug" may or may not be processed by developers, but what happens when the post is closed ?

If I report a bug, and it's (wrongfully, and let's assume I speak in broader terms than my particular question) marked as duplicate, will developers look at it at all ?

Comment: It's the same as getting duped on the main site - if you disagree, then **edit your question** to clarify how it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's not the issue here.

Comment: Then what *is* the issue?

Comment: I'm sorry, but have you read my question? `If I report a bug, and it's marked as duplicate, will developers look at it at all ?`

Comment: Given that they don't guarantee to look at the ones that *aren't* duplicates, why would they for ones that are? It would probably reduce the likelihood, unless it gets lots of upvotes in its own right.

Comment: Probably, No. Because there are (probably) more than 100 questions tagged with [meta-tag:bug] asked every single day on the whole stack exchange network. You can imagine the rest...

Comment: Ok so my bug will never be fixed because some people marked it as duplicate without even reading it. Great!

Answer (score 1):

I started the close voting on the question you're talking about.

I can assure you that I read the initial revision of your question thoroughly which lead me to choose the duplicate that your question got closed against. What might have biased me is that I answered that duplicate so I was familiar with the topic.

In general I close questions against duplicates if I expect the answer would be the same. I don't respect tags for that matter, so if you have a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) I happily close against a question tagged  [support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/support) if the answer would fit. Some might curse me for that, some don't care, some might cheer. The duplicate in this case was also tagged similar to yours and although your repro steps were slightly different the answer would fit in my opinion and the other reviewers agreed but that was all before your revision.

I don't think questions tagged bug that are closed are considered as input by the team. The question I linked to is still open so that one is on the bug-list for sure. Your now closed question is linked to that duplicate. I expect the team to visit/check the duplicates in case they consider taking that bug on.

I'm not 100% convinced that every bug that has a slight variation in repro steps is a bug on their own but I'm not going to get lured into a close/re-open war if others see it differently.

<sup>sidenote: posting a bug doesn't guarantee it gets fixed, not within [6 to 8 units](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514)</sup>

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation (both for my other question and the probability of the bug being fixed some day)